# Dictionary value by key

Tags: dictionary, key, swift, subscript

While trying to get a value from a `Dictionary`, Xcode is showing me the following error:

> Could not find an overload for 'subscript' that accepts the supplied arguments

```
class func fromDictionary(enterpriseDictionary:Dictionary<String, AnyObject>) -> Enterprise
{
    var enterprise:Enterprise = Enterprise()

    enterprise.id = enterpriseDictionary["id"] as Int  (ERROR OCCURS HERE)
    enterprise.name = enterpriseDictionary["name"] as? String ( AND HERE )


    return enterprise
}
```

Comment: Can you show the calling code?

Comment: Yeah I guess `Int` and `String` aren't objects, so `Any` is what you want.  You can't downcast an object to a primitive type, the compiler can see that coming a mile away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve this question by replacing the "AnyObject" by "Any" as seen below:

```
class func fromDictionary(enterpriseDictionary:Dictionary<String, Any>) -> Enterprise
{
    var enterprise:Enterprise = Enterprise()

    enterprise.id = enterpriseDictionary["id"] as Int
    enterprise.name = enterpriseDictionary["name"] as? String


    return enterprise
}
```

As @Andrey Tarantsov said:

This occurs because AnyObject is for any class instance (you can also think of it as objects in Objective-C sense); String and Int are not classes.

Comment: Because AnyObject is for any _class instance_ (you can also think of it as objects in Objective-C sense); String and Int are not classes.